# In Qt, how do I convert the Unicode codepoint U+1F64B to a QString holding its equivalent character ""?

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, qstring, qchar

### Background:

I am making a hash that will allow you to lookup the description you see below by feeding it a QString containing its character.

[image: Character map example]

I got a full list of the relevant data, looking something like this:

```
QHash<QString, QString> lookupCharacterDescription;
...
lookupCharacterDescription.insert("003F","QUESTION MARK");
lookupCharacterDescription.insert("0040","COMMERCIAL AT");
lookupCharacterDescription.insert("0041","LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A");
lookupCharacterDescription.insert("0042","LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B");
...
lookupCharacterDescription.insert("1F648","SEE-NO-EVIL MONKEY");
lookupCharacterDescription.insert("1F649","HEAR-NO-EVIL MONKEY");
lookupCharacterDescription.insert("1F64A","SPEAK-NO-EVIL MONKEY");
lookupCharacterDescription.insert("1F64B","HAPPY PERSON RAISING ONE HAND");
...
lookupCharacterDescription.insert("FFFD","REPLACEMENT CHARACTER");
lookupCharacterDescription.insert("FFFE","<not a character>");
lookupCharacterDescription.insert("FFFF","<not a character>");
lookupCharacterDescription.insert("FFFFE","<not a character>");
lookupCharacterDescription.insert("FFFFF","<not a character>");
```

Now obviously `"1F64B"` needs to be wrapped in something here. I have tried playing around with things like `0x1F64B` as a QChar, but I am honestly groping in the dark here. I could make it work with the lower values like the Latin Letters, but it fails with the 5 character addresses.

### Questions:

- How do I classify `1F64B`?
- Is this considered UTF-32?
- What can I wrap this value "1F64B" in to produce the QString("")?
- Will the wrappings also work for the lower values?

Comment: What exactly happens when "it fails"? You might need to specify a font that actually has the unusual characters you want to display.

Comment: the part after `U+` is simply a 21-bit number. Thus sing a string for the key would be somewhat inefficient. And the correct term for that is a *code point*

Comment: @aschepler It gives me a different character. Thus when I output `QString("")`, it shows up correctly in my terminal. Trying to do so with ... `QString(0x1F64B);` gives me an entirely different character, `` which looks like an 8.

Comment: The `lookupCharacterDescription` table code has nothing to do with the question. For that matter the question doesn't seem to have anything to do with Qt either. To specify a Unicode character you can either type it directly in the source code, when you use a Unicode encoding for the source code, or you can use the `\U` notation, e.g. `L"The Unicode \U0001F64B hand symbol, ."`.

Comment: Note that `QString` has static `fromUcs4()` methods that can be used to create a `QString` from 1+ Unicode codepoint(s) numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `QString(0x1F64B)` it'll call [`QString::QString(QChar ch)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-2). Since `QChar` is a 16-bit type, it'll **truncate** the value to 0xF64B and you get an invalid character since that code point is currently unassigned. I'm pretty sure you'll get an out-of-range warning at that line. You can see the value `F64B` easily in the character `` if you zoom in or use a hex editor. Since there's no way for 0x1F64B to fit into a single 16-bit QChar and must be represented by a surrogate pair, you can't initialize the string that way.

OTOH `QString("")` works since it's constructing the string *from another string*. You must construct the string with a string like that, or manually by assigning the UTF-8/16 code units.

> Is this considered UTF-32?

No. UTF-32 is a Unicode encoding that uses 32 bits for a code unit. You only have QString and not a bare byte array, so you don't need to care about its underlying encoding (which is actually UTF-16)

> What can I wrap this value "1F64B" in to produce the QString("")?

You shouldn't deal with the numeric values as string. Store it as a numeric type instead

```
QHash<qint32, QString> lookupCharacterDescription;
lookupCharacterDescription.insert(0x1F64B, "HAPPY PERSON RAISING ONE HAND");
```

and then to make a string that contains the character at code point 0x1F64B use

```
uint cp = 0x1F64B;
QString mystr = QString::fromUcs4(&cp, 1);
```

> Will the wrappings also work for the lower values?

Yes, since UCS4, A.K.A. UTF-32, can store any possible Unicode characters

Alternatively you can construct the character from UTF-16 or UTF-8. U+1F64B is encoded in UTF-16 as `D83D DE4B`, or as `F0 9F 99 8B` in UTF-8, therefore you can use any of the below

```
QChar utf16[2] = { 0xD38D, 0xDE4B };
str1 = QString(utf16, 2);
char* utf8[4] = { 0xF0, 0x9F, 0x99, 0x8B };
str2 = QString::fromUtf8(utf8, 4);
```

If you want to include the string in its literal form in source code then either of the following will work

```
str1 = QString::fromWCharArray(L"\xD83D\xDE4B");
str2 = QString::fromUtf8("\xF0\x9F\x99\x8B");
```

If you have C++11 support then simply use the prefix `u8`, `u` and `U` for UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 respectively like

```
u8""
u""
U""
u8"\U0001F64B"
u"\U0001F64B"
u"\uD83D\uDE4B"
U"\U0001F64B"
```

Mandatory article to understand text and encodings: [There Ain't No Such Thing as Plain Text](https://blog.codinghorror.com/there-aint-no-such-thing-as-plain-text/)